# Como adicionar dois valores?

Tags: php, mysql

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($row['level'] == '1') //COMO ADICIONO PARA OUTRO NIVEL CONSEGUIR VER ESTA PAGINA?
    {
        echo('OLAAAA');
    }
    else
    {
        echo('NAO TENS ACESSO A ESTA PAGINA');
    }
}
```

Como adiciono o outro user com outro valor para também poder ver a página? Sem ser só o que tem o valor de `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso seja para ele ver a mesma página que o usuário com level 1 utilize o código abaixo:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($row['level'] == '**1**' || $row['level'] == '**2**' || $row['level'] == '**3**')
    {
        echo('OLAAAA');
    }
    else
    {
        echo('NAO TENS ACESSO A ESTA PAGINA');
    }
}
```

Caso seja para ele ver uma página diferente de quem está no level 1 utilize:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        if($row['level'] == '**1**')
        {
            echo 'OLAAAA';
        }
       else if($row['level'] == '**2**')
       {
            echo 'Level 2';
       }
        else
        {
            echo('NAO TENS ACESSO A ESTA PAGINA');
        }
    }
```

Comment: OBRIGADO PELA AJUDA !

Comment: Por nada! Por gentileza, se você puder marcar como pergunta certa para orientar outros usuários que possam estar com dúvidas em algo parecido, eu agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Você só precisa permitir outro nível dentro do IF, com o operador `||`. Algo assim:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($row['level'] == '1' || $row['level'] == '2') // Agora nível 1 e 2 podem ver.
    {
        echo('OLAAAA');
    }
    else
    {
        echo('NAO TENS ACESSO A ESTA PAGINA');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($row['level'] == '**1**')
    {
        echo('OLAAAA');
    } elseif ($row['level'] == '**2**') {
        echo('OLAAAA USER 2');
}
    else
    {
        echo('NAO TENS ACESSO A ESTA PAGINA');
    }
}
```

Comment: isso eu sei fazer, mas na mesma linha do if($row['level'] == '1') nao da para fazer tipo: if($row['level'] == '1', '2') ?

Comment: Ahhhh sim, if($row['level'] == '1' OR '$row['level'] == '2')